# Could not find any valid local directory for jobcache EXCEPTION Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop and I'm getting the following exception when I try to run my job on Hadoop cluster:

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for jobcache/job_201409031055_3865/jars/job.jar
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:376)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.localizeJobJarFile(JobLocalizer.java:268)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.localizeJobFiles(JobLocalizer.java:380)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.localizeJobFiles(JobLocalizer.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.initializeJob(DefaultTaskController.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1381)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java
```

Can anyone please tell me what seems to be the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MR store intermediate data during map reduce job in local directory. It will be in `mapreduce.cluster.local.dir` in mapred-site.xml.

Please verify you have enough space in the directory based on your input file size. Also, you can try to  compress the intermediate output files to minimize the space consumption.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way that I could check this using the web interface for HDFS?

Comment: I do not think so, you can check that in web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. When I check disk info of that node, I came to know that it is about 100% used. So I added a new disk in that node (change hdfs-site.xml dfs.data.dir ) accordingly. Then restarted that node daemons and my problem was resolved.